# Menu links can be clicked but do not load

Tags: html, shopify

This site is on Shopify and the main menu links are not working consistently.

```
https://www.fisherwallace.com/
```

No console errors.

Links lower in the page work, but not main menu ones.

Any suggestions on how I can identify the issue?

Comment: it is working. Can you check again?

Comment: works fine for me

Comment: Just got a txt from Shopify that they were having issues. Hopefully, that was it. Thanks all!